# Enviar email direto do Aplicativo

Tags: android, email

tem como enviar um email com uma sugestão direto do Aplicativo, sem abrir um aplicativo externo, tipo Gmail? Exemplo:

Um campo onde a pessoa coloca o email e um outro campo ela por a sugestão e  um botão de enviar. Após todo o preenchimento quando ela tocar no botão enviar, o email é disparado, sem abrir o aplicativo padrão de e-mail que está configurado no smartphone?

Eu fiz um teste com o código abaixo, ele funciona porém ele abre a aplicação externa.

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Envie sua sugestão para o nosso email", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Enviar", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto"));
                            email.setType("message/rfc822");
                            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                                    new String[]{"aquieucolocomeuemaildecontato"});
                            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                                    "Sugestão: ");
                            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Olá " + "");
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "ENVIAR E-MAIL"));
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Siga esse tutorial que você irá conseguir enviar email direto do app sem necessidade de utilizar outros aplicativos externos.

[link](http://www.luiztools.com.br/post/como-criar-um-aplicativo-android-que-envia-emails/)

Comment: @Henqsan visualizei aqui, vou testar depois mas já ajudou aqui. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, isto é possível ! Mas você precisará desenvolver uma [API](http://www.up.edu.br/blogs/engenharia-da-computacao/2016/07/01/o-que-e-uma-api/) que faça isso para você. Esta api vai executar em um servidor/cloud (o que vai exigir que o celular tenha conexão com a internet) que vai receber a chamada do seu aplicativo contendo as informações que vão ser enviadas por email e vai fazer esse envio para você.

Com uma busca rápida você pode descobrir como fazer isso usando a linguagem de sua preferência, vou listar dois links que podem te ajudar a implementar isso de maneira bem fácil:

- [PHP](http://www.devmedia.com.br/enviando-email-com-php/37216)
- [Node](https://alanhoff.com/posts/enviando-email-no-nodejs.html)

Caso queira facilitar ainda mais a sua vida, utilize o [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) ou o [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) para te auxiliar com estes envios